# Avoiding Pitfalls with Assigning Falsy Values in Defaults?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway that we can deal with falsy values in || operators that are lazily evaluated?

So, for example if we have:

```
function isOldEnough(age) {
   age = age || 18;
   return age;
}

isOldEnough(0) // returns 18 because 0 is falsy
```

In ES6, you can simply declare it like

```
function isOldEnough(age = 18) { ... }
```

Is there anythning we can do in ES5 to avoid this issue?

Comment: use `null != value` accounts for both `undefined` and `null` but not for `false` or `0`

Comment: I would really only use || if I know an object is being passed in. Perhaps it's better to check if age is equal to undefined?

Comment: on the other hand if you want to handle `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`, empty strings/arrays uniformly as `false` use `!!value`, it will transform `value` to boolean handling empty/undefined values as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like (if I understood correctly):

```
function isOldEnough(age) {
  var age = typeof age === "number" ? arguments[0] : 18;
  return age; 
}

isOldEnough(null) // returns 18
isOldEnough("") // returns 18
isOldEnough(undefined) // returns 18
isOldEnough(0) // returns 0
```

Could be further improved with checking if age is equal to or greater than zero etc

Comment: what happens if you use `isOldEnough(new Number(3))` ? ;)

Comment: i think a return is missing both from the answr and original question, something should be returned form the function as [@Palle Due](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5516339/palle-due) noticed